# JDBC update prepared statement not showing updates

Tags: jdbc, prepared-statement

I have two JDBC SQL prepared statements in the program to UPDATE tables (different areas of program). When I run the statement, I can see the updates in MySQL when I query the table. So I know the update is happening. However, I have a table connected to the DB in the program that does not show the updated results unless I stop running the program and restart it. Then the updates show in the table. I have other prepared statements that use INSERT INTO and these changes show up right away in the tables (I don't have to stop-restart my program). I don't know if the problem lies in the UPDATE, or in my code (the usual culprit), or some setting I have wrong. I think I might be passing things wrong between method calls. This is part of what it does: I have an income table, the user creates a new income listing, and part of that listing gets sent to a FUNDS table (with the UPDATE statement) and another part gets sent to an INCOME table (with the INSERT INTO statement). Here is the code, thanks for help and suggestions!

```
     //Get user info
         Income income = new Income();
         Funds fund = new Funds();
         income.setIncomeName(jTextField10.getText());
         String budgetAmt = jTextField11.getText();
         BigDecimal bAmt = new BigDecimal(budgetAmt);
         income.setAmount(bAmt);
         income.setDescription(jTextArea3.getText());
         String iDate = jTextField12.getText();
         Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(iDate);
         java.util.Date utilDate = date;
         java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
         income.setDateReceived(sqlDate);
         s = (String)jList10.getSelectedValue().toString();
         income.setFundAllocation(s);

         // Send info to be processed in FUND table with UPDATE - start of problem area
         FundsSvcJDBCImpl fundImpl = new FundsSvcJDBCImpl();                
         Funds calculateFundAmt = fundImpl.calculateFundAmt(fund, income);

         // Send info to be process in INCOME table - this part works   
         IncomeSvcJDBCImpl budgetImpl = new IncomeSvcJDBCImpl();
         Income addIncome = budgetImpl.addIncome(income);


        //This is the part of the FundsSvcJDBCImpl that uses the UPDATE statement

        public Funds calculateFundAmt (Funds fund, Income income) throws Exception {
        Statement stmt = null;
        int max = 0;
        BigDecimal fundTotal = new BigDecimal(0);
        Connection conn = getConnection();

        try{
            stmt = conn.createStatement();

            String sql1 = "SELECT sum(Amount) As fundTotal FROM funds WHERE FundsName = ?";
            PreparedStatement pstmt1 = conn.prepareStatement(sql1);
            pstmt1.setString(1, income.getFundAllocation());
            ResultSet rs2 = pstmt1.executeQuery();
            while(rs2.next()){       
                fundTotal = fundTotal.add(rs2.getBigDecimal("fundTotal"));   
            }

            fundTotal = fundTotal.add(income.getAmount());

            String sql2 =    "UPDATE funds SET Amount = ? WHERE FundsName = ?";
            PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql2);
            pstmt.setBigDecimal(1, fundTotal);
            pstmt.setString(2, income.getFundAllocation());
            pstmt.executeUpdate(); 

         }
        catch (Exception e){
            throw e;
        }
        finally {
            if (conn != null){
                conn.close();  
                stmt.close();               
            }                 
        }

     return fund;
 }
```

Comment: Is it possible you're running into a [repeatable read isolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)#Repeatable_reads) issue?  In your thread that you are looking for changes in, instead of closing and restarting the program, can you close and restart the transaction?

Comment: hmm, I am not sure. Before closing and restarting my program, I can query the table in MySQL and see the updates. So the DBMS isn't preventing the updates from being seen. I am just not seeing them on my JTable. I double-checked and with each update to the DBMS I have close() methods, so the transaction should be ended, right?

Comment: Right, if the updating transaction wasn't closed you wouldn't be able to see the change when you log into the database manually.  However, I'm wondering about the line "I have a table connected to the program that does not show the updates".  I assume you mean that you have a spot in your program where you are reading to check if there are updates.  Is that connection closed and reopened?  Do you have that code?

Comment: I understand now...that is a JTable that is bound to the DB table. The code is auto-generated. The table is opened by clicking on a menu item in the main frame. Not all the information on the table is entered with the UPDATE statement. Some of it is entered first by an INSERT INTO statement. That change shows up right away...only when I update the row does it not (I close and re-open the frame that contains the JTable, which only shows INSERT INTO changes, not UPDATE).

Comment: What framework/library are you using the bind the JTable into the DB table?